# Codeigniter Cache file time to live doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I used cache-file to store some data on my app :

I save the cacahe by this method :

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->cache->file->save($cacheKey, $data, 60);
```

I expect the cache will be gone after 60 seconds At this time when i post this question (at 8.27 PM), file is still there

[image: file cache]

How to solve this ?

Comment: The TTL indicates the time upto which the content of the cache file is valid, not when the file will be deleted.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i see, then how to autodelete after desired time in CI ? Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: If you use CodeIgniter, you hand over some of the control to that platform. There's no earthly reason why you would want control over the auto-deletion of cache files, so it doesn't exist. At least not in the documentation. You could write something that will use [delete](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/caching.html#CI_Cache::delete), using a cron job. But I strongly advice against that. The cache file will be deleted when the platform decides it is time to delete it. Don't fret about it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware so i use the cache to store validated spreadsheet data, and it will be available to the users to download. So in my opinion there's probability when user don't want or forget to download it, hence i need the autodeletion after specific time. But if so, maybe i will use the delete cache when user being logged out instead.